# Getting my data to be focused on one state

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, data

I have a map I'm working on for a final project and I'm a bit stuck as what to do moving forward.

I have a map I'm making for forest fires and the type of tree in that area and I'm trying to get it zoned in on Colorado. I have the [shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) for Colorado in my map and I have the forest fire information, and I even have a map of the US for the type of tree in each location.

But what I'm stuck at is trying to get my map to only be focused on Colorado so when I calculate the type of tree on each data point it will only be for Colorado.

Sorry if this is a bit convoluted but I'm just a bit confused and stuck right now. The tree information on my map is an [`.img`](http://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000420.shtml) file. I'm using ArcGIS 10.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clip the raster data `.img` data by the shapefile of Colorado. You can do that using the [Clip tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) in ArcGIS. You need to go to `Data Management -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip` to do the job. Make sure both raster and shapefile of Colorado have the same coordinate system (projection). Also, make sure `Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry` is checked.